# Error message generated by python code from book

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, vpython

I'm learning python and have been working thru some examples in a book. I've run many codes and they have run fine but I'm having trouble with one. I'm using python 3.6 on an iMac with High Sierra. My short code is here:

```
from vpython import *

dx=0.04; dx2=dx*dx; k0=5.5*pi; dt=dx2/20.0; xmax=6.0
xs = arange(-xmax,xmax+dx/2, dx)

g=graph(width=500,height=250,title="wave packet")
PlotObj=curve(x=xs, color=color.yellow, radius=0.1)
g.center = (0,2,0)

psr = exp(-0.5*(xs/0.5)**2) * cos(k0*xs)
psi = exp(-0.5*(xs/0.5)**2) * sin(k0*xs)
v = 15.0*xs**2

while True:
    rate(500)
    psr[1:-1]= psr[1:-1]-(dt/dx2)*(psi[2:]+psi[:-2]-2*psi[1:-1])+dt*v[1:-1]*psi[1:-1]
    psi[1:-1]= psi[1:-1]-(dt/dx2)*(psr[2:]+psr[:-2]-2*psr[1:-1])+dt*v[1:-1]*psr[1:-1]
    PlotObj.y = 4*(psr**2 + psi**2)
```

The error message generated is below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "harmosanimate.py", line 10, in <module>
    psr = exp(-0.5*(xs/0.5)**2) * cos(k0*xs)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: `from vpython import *` is *terrible, terrible* practice.

Comment: what would you suggest?  I tried vpython.graph but I got a different error message that no module graph was found.

Comment: I would suggest not using starred imports. It's impossible to tell what any of your functions do. We can only *assume* they come from the `numpy` namespace.

Comment: i'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: It won't eliminate your error, but at least you should know where everything is coming from. I suspect either `exp` or `cos` are actually `math.exp` or `math.cos`, rather than `numpy.exp` or `numpy.cos`, and the `math` versions will throw that error if you pass them an array.

Comment: yes the book commented using from vpython import * because it used several functions that were enabled by calling it like that. it also uses arange and I don't know how to get that otherwise.

Comment: that's `numpy.arange` presumably.  This is the *reason you shouldn't do imports like this*

Comment: i hear you. I was just going thru examples in the book... I'll try to find a work around.

Comment: `import numpy as np` and replace all calls to `cos` and `exp` with `np.cos` and `np.exp`

Comment: i just did that.  now i get the error message that overflow encountered in the lines at the bottom for psi and psr. thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - i found a mistake in my coding so your suggestion about adding np worked. if you put that in as an answer I'll check it as being right. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing this:

from numpy import arange, exp, cos, sin

With this import the program still fails, but that's a different issue; I didn't attempt to debug the program.

For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users